# belongsTo through a join table

Tags: mysql, cakephp, model-associations

I have `User` which **can** belong to one and only one `Partner`.

So instead of having a `Users.partner_id` field `null` most of the time, I though creating a `partners_users` table.

But that way I have to declare a `belongsToMany` association which doesn't exactly represent the situation.
I could declare `partners_users.user_id` `UNIQUE` in the table.

What's your opinion?

Comment: It looks good as User belongs to Partner and Partner has many User. Why you need belongsToMany there ?

Comment: @ManoharKhadka I need a belongsToMany association because in CakePHP3, it's the only way to specify a join table AFAIK. the belongsTo association suppose a `partner_id` field inside the `Users` table which is I would avoid as it will be occasionnally used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The association you're describing is VERY standard and is a belongsTo/hasMany association. Keep the `Users.partner_id` field, whether it's used much or not.  There's no reason to add an extra table.

Comment: Proper database design/normalization is an excellent reason to add an extra table separating and representing Partners. The real question is whether it is pragmatic or not.